# is it possible to queue multiple Print Jobs in Android using Print API?

Tags: android, printing, printdocument

So far I'm able to print a single PDF document stored on my external storage. But I want give print command for multiple documents. (Queueing Print Jobs)

So first question is that

is it possible to queue printing of all documents without showing dialog for each document?

if yes, How?

Thanks in advance!

This is the code I have tried so far.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CancellationSignal;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.print.PageRange;
import android.print.PrintAttributes;
import android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter;
import android.print.PrintDocumentInfo;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


public class PDFPrintDocumentAdapter extends PrintDocumentAdapter {

      private Context context;
      private String filePath;
      private String fileName;

/**
 * @param context
 * @param fileName - for Print Document Info
 * @param filePath - PDF file to be printed, stored in external storage
 */
public PDFPrintDocumentAdapter(Context context, String fileName, String filePath) {

    this.context = context;
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.filePath = filePath;

}

@Override
public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras) {

    if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
        callback.onLayoutCancelled();
        return;
    }

    PrintDocumentInfo pdi = new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder(fileName).setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT).build();

    callback.onLayoutFinished(pdi, true);
}

@Override
public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback) {

    InputStream input = null;
    OutputStream output = null;

    try {

        input = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        output = new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor());

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
            output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES});

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ee) {
        //Catch exception
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Catch exception
    } finally {
        try {
            if (null != input) {
                input.close();
            }
            if (null != output) {
                output.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onFinish() {
    super.onFinish();

    Toast.makeText(context, "Printing is completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}



}
```